# How to register a legacy typelib (.tlb) on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, typelib, regtlib

I have a new PC running Windows 7 and Visual Studio 2010, and need to register a legacy typelib (.tlb) to interface with an existing legacy application.  However, regtlib.exe does not seem to be part of Windows 7 (I don't think it was part of Vista either), and regtlibv12.exe, available as part of Visual Studio 2005, seems to have disappeared with Visual Studio 2008 (and certainly Visual Studio 2010).

Microsoft forums and knowledge base articles refer to RegAsm.exe.  I've tried RegAsm.exe, but that will only create and register a typelib from an existing dll or assembly (which I do not have).  I can't believe there is no way to register an existing typelib on Windows 7.  Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Well, I guess I can answer my own question (and for anyone else who has the same problem):

Apparently, regtlibv12.exe is part of Visual Studio 2010 (contrary to what I read on various Microsoft forums), but it is located in the Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30139 folder (not the v2.0.50727 folder).  Using that executable I was able to successfully register the legacy typelib (.tlb).

Comment: Just to add some data... I have the following frameworks installed: 1.0, 1.1, 2.0, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0.  I have VS 6.0, 2005, 2008, and 2010 installed. I have regtlbv12.exe in the 2.0 and 4.0 framework folders.

Comment: Also, to UNregister a .tlb file, use: regtlibv12.exe -u myFile.tlb

Answer (score 8):

It comes with `.Net` framework installation. On my machine I found it as:

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\regtlibv12.exe
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\regtlibv12.exe
```

Comment: Funny, I have these frameworks installed and then some.  `regtlibv12.exe` is nowhere to be found.  Although I see a `RegAsm.exe` and I have read that people were using that to try and register.

Answer (score 4):

There is also C:\WINDOWS\REGTLIB.EXE that seems to be part of a standard Windows 7 installation.

Comment: Not on my Windows 7 its not.

Comment: If it's Windows 7 64bit, then try checking here: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\URTTEMP

Comment: I realise I'm a bit late to this party and the question is regarding Windows 7, but I just thought I'd mention this is the correct answer on Windows 10 Professional 64 bit 21H2.

Answer (score 1):

From a `Developer Command Prompt for VS2013`, you can use the `regtlib.exe` command.

To find the Developer Command Prompt for VS2013 you can try looking under Start -> All Programs -> Visual Studio 2013 -> Developer Command prompt for VS2013.