# Can't register tlb on other computer

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, dll, vb6, tlbimp

I could create a dll from vb.net visual studio 2012 and using options, register for COM interop, this has generated me a .tlb file, the same been able to reference it from a project in vb6 and use its features, all this is happening in my pc.

But from another pc it does not work, I get the following error.

Run -Time 429:
ActiveX component can't create object

I tried some methods but nothing works for me.

Comment: What methods? Where any of them using regasm to register the your dll on the other PC?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to register a legacy typelib (.tlb) on Windows 7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4527213/how-to-register-a-legacy-typelib-tlb-on-windows-7)

Comment: Have you tried `regasm /tlb /codebase AssemblyName.dll` ? Then reference the resulting .tlb file

Answer (score 2):

RegAsm requires admin permissions. Export as a reg file, search for `HKCR` and replace `hkcu\software\classes` and merge. This allows per user install.

If on 64 bit make sure you are using 32 bit components and programs.