# "Cannot get the file path for type library" trying to use OCX in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, com, activex

I am rewriting an old VB6 application in c# on a Win10Pro64bit computer.  The VB6 app uses an OCX called IMAGinE.  I am able to add the control to the ToolBox.  When I do, it adds two references:  AxIMAGINELib and IMAGINELib.  The IMAGINELib references has the little yellow triangle signifying there is an issue with the reference.  I am able to add the control to the form.  In the properties, it shows it is of type "AxIMAGINELib.AxIMAGinE".  When I try to run the application, I get the following error in the "Error List" tab of VS:

```
Could not resolve COM reference "8a4feb20-a486-11cf-be99-0020afd208b9" version 1.0. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

When I go to the Output tab of VS, it shows the following warning immediately preceding the above error:

```
Cannot get the file path for type library "bef6e001-a874-101a-8bba-00aa00300cab" version 2.0. Library not registered. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002801D (TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED))
```

A brief search seems to indicate that "bef6e001-a874-101a-8bba-00aa00300cab" points to olepro32.dll.

I have registered the OCX using regsvr32, both in the windows\system32 directory and windows\syswow64 directories.  I registered olepro32.dll in the syswow64 directory, but not in the system32 directory because it didn't exist.  Doing this did not change anything.

I removed the IMAGINELib reference and kept the AxIMAGINELib reference, thinking it wouldn't need both references and because the IMAGINELib reference had the little yellow triangle.  Doing this did not change anything.

The company that created the original OCX is no longer in business, and I do not have the original component installer.

Any ideas what I can do to get this OCX working ?  I don't want to use the OCX on a form.  I need to access information that only the OCX can read.  Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to use this component in x86 or x64? How how your program compiled? x86? x64?

Comment: Currently I am using AnyCPU.  I tried x86, and it made no difference.

Comment: Maybe these components come with an external .tlb that needs to be registered also. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4527213/how-to-register-a-legacy-typelib-tlb-on-windows-7

Comment: No .tlb files were found.

Comment: No, registration is gone on Win10.  Low odds that you'll be able to find regtlibv12.exe, you need a Win7 or XP machine to get ahead.